# Selecting an action based on Expected Utility

Tags: decision-tree

Please I would like to know What happens if there are equal high expected utilities (EU) corresponding to different actions. In such case do you randomly choose any high EU and perform the corresponding action.

Answer (score 1):

Expected Utility is just a decision criterion. If you find 2 actions have the same utility value, then as long as your decision criterion is not changed, you can pick any of them randomly. But, in order to make a better decision, when you find 2 actions have the same utility value, you may need to think about some other criterion so that they can be differentiated.

Think about the real-life scenario. You are hiring 2 candidates. And your selection criterion is that, whoever has more years of experience, he/she will be selected. Then you found that Candidate A and Candidate B, both of them have 6 years of experiences. Now, what? you do not hire them both (unless you have 2 positions open). Then you change your decision criterion such that whoever got highest GPA in the University, he will be selected. Chances are that you will find one of them has better GPA than the other. So, you can choose one of them based on Higher GPA. But, say, you found that both of them got GPA 3.5. Now, what, still you can find another decision criterion. Something like, whoever lives in the local city will get more preference than who lives very far from the office. In that way, you can continue changing your criterion to find the best candidate to select. BUT, yes, if you do not change your criterion once you found both options have the same value, then you have no way to select just one.

In decision analysis, there are many [decision criteria](https://www.spicelogic.com/docs/DecisionTreeAnalyzer/intro/decision-criteria-333) you can apply. Maximize Expected Utility, Maximin, Minimax Regret etc. You can also apply Dominance, like [Stochastic Dominance](https://www.spicelogic.com/docs/DecisionTreeAnalyzer/analysis/stochastic-dominance-324), or Mean-Variance dominance. For example, if you find that both options have same Expected Value, you can check which option has Lower Standard Deviation (or variance).

Here, I show you an example of Decision Tree with the SpiceLogic [Decision Tree software](https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/decision-tree-maker-27).

Say, you have a decision tree as shown below. Both of the actions have the same expected value "50 Utils". Therefore, you cannot choose any of the action based on "Maximize Expected Utility". Once you change the Decision Criterion from the ribbon to Maximin (Maximin means, select action based on the worst case scenario), you will see the "Action 2" is selected.

[image: SpiceLogic Decision Tree Maker Software]